# How to except columns in join query?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm using clickhouse-server.
I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    pid Int64,
    timestamp DateTime,
    data1 Float32,
    data2 Float32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (timestamp);
```

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(
    pid Int64,
    timestamp DateTime,
    data3 Float32,
    data4 Float32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (timestamp);
```

`pid` and `timestamp` matches in these tables
I wish to select everything from both tables where `timestamp` matches.
Here is a query I came up with:

```
select * from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.timestamp = table2.timestamp
```

It works but selects `pid` and `timestamp` twice.
How to exclude unneeded `pid` and `timestamp` from `table2`?

I've tried to `EXCEPT` timestamp but it seems to be needed for join.
Have to notice that it is simplified example. Real tables have much more columns.

Comment: Name the columns you want in the SELECT statement.

`SELECT t1.*, t2.data3, t2.data4 FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp`

Comment: @Magictallguy thx, but naming columns is hard when there are a lot of them

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT (`table2.pid`, `table2.timestamp`)
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.timestamp = table2.timestamp
)
```

Comment: Documentation of this is here: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/#except

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with this, without second query:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT `pid` FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` USING (`pid`,`timestamp`)
```